# How to convert a defaultdict(list) to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, defaultdict

I have a defaultdict(list) object that is of this structure:

```
{id: [list[list]]}
```

for example,

```
'a1': [[0.01, 'cat']],

'a2': [[0.09, 'cat']],

'a3': [[0.5, 'dog']],
```

...

I'd like to conver this `defaultdict(list)` into a `Pandas DataFrame` object.

I tried with the following:

`df = pd.DataFrame(list(my_dict.items()), columns=['id', 'category'])`

However, I faced a problem with my 'category' column. This is a column of list of list. I'm trying to split out the 2 values in the 'category' into 2 separate columns. So my final DataFrame columns would be ['id', 'score', 'category'].

When I tried with below Apply function:

`db['category'].apply(lambda x: x[0][0])`

I got an error for 'list index out of range'.

What could be wrong with my code? How shall I create the 2 new columns from a list of lists?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[k] + v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items()], 
                   columns=['id', 'score', 'category'])
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, v[0][0], v[0][1]) for k, v in my_dict.items()], 
                   columns=['id', 'score', 'category'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'a1': [[0.01, 'cat']], 'a2': [[0.09, 'cat']],'a3': [[0.5, 'dog']]}


df = pd.DataFrame([[k] + j for k,v in d.items() for j in v], columns=['id', 'score', 'category'])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   id  score category
0  a1   0.01      cat
1  a3   0.50      dog
2  a2   0.09      cat
```

Comment: I got the error "can only concatenate list (not "float") to list" with your code above

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to do this.
I used the pandas explode function.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

# Create Default Dict
dd = defaultdict(list)
dd['a1'].append(0.01)
dd['a1'].append('cat')
dd['a2'].append(0.09)
dd['a2'].append('cat')
dd['a3'].append(0.5)
dd['a3'].append('dog')
dd['a3'].append('mouse')
dd['b'].append('barco')

# Transform in Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd.items())
df.columns = ['key', 'values']
df = df.explode('values')
df
```

I believe this is a cleaner way to do this...