# How to convert defaultdict to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a defaultdict named 'sum_vol', which I need to convert to a dataframe:

```
defaultdict(int,
            {2930.0: 2838,
             2930.25: 677,
             2930.5: 2780,
             2931.0: 2005,
             2931.75: 1402,
             2932.0: 711,
             2932.5: 2982,
             2931.5: 1500,
             2932.75: 7973,
             2933.0: 12170,
             2933.75: 10009,
             2934.5: 49867,
             2932.25: 1758....
```

I tried to convert it to a list first but I failed already with this step, because it cuts off the second value:

```
strlist = ":".join(str(x) for x in sum_vol)
newdf = pd.DataFrame([x for x in strlist.split(': ')], columns =['close'])
```

I get:

```
    close
0   2930.0
1   2930.25
2   2930.5
3   2931.0
4   2931.75
...
```

But my desired output is:

```
    close     vol
0   2930.0    2838
1   2930.25    677
2   2930.5    2780
3   2931.0    2005
4   2931.75   1402
```

How can I get the 2nd values of the dict to a 2nd column in the new dataframe?

Comment: look here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54122942/how-to-convert-a-defaultdictlist-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: You might need this, ```pd.DataFrame([{"close":k, "vol": v} for k,v in sum_vol.items()])```

Comment: @flynn1973 I tried it but it doesn't work. I get an error: `'str' object has no attribute 'items'`

Answer (score 1):

Use 'from_dict':

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient="index")
```

The output is:

```
             0
2930.00   2838
2930.25    677
2930.50   2780
2931.00   2005
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(you_dict.items(), columns=['close', 'vol'])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     close   vol
0  2930.00  2838
1  2930.25   677
2  2930.50  2780
3  2931.00  2005
4  2931.75  1402
5  2932.00   711
6  2932.50  2982
```